# Apache Solr: database indexing

Tags: database, indexing, solr

I'm working on a database sql that has this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news` (
    `idNews` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `url` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `date` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `title` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `descr` TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idNews`));

INSERT INTO `myDb`.`news` (`url`, `date`, `title`, `descr`) 
VALUES(...), ..., (...);
```

Now I want to create an index on this database to improve the performance.

If I use a mysql syntax:

```
CREATE INDEX `newsIndex` ON `news`(`idNews`, `url`, `date`, `title`, `descr`);
```

I have an error like this:

```
#1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'url' used in key specification without a key length
```

The error happens because MySQL can index only the first N chars of a BLOB or TEXT column. The solution to the problem is to remove the TEXT or BLOB column from the index or unique constraint, or set another field as primary key.
But I want to preserve that structure with TEXT columns.

So I discover Apache Solr, an open source enterprise search platform, written in Java, from the Apache Lucene project. Its major features include full-text search, hit highlighting, etc.

The problem is that Solr is used to index documents and I don't understand the way to use it to index my database.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Solr is a standalone search engine that lives aside your MySQL DB. You should read [the Solr introduction](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Getting+Started) in the reference and then have a look at [the dataimport handler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler). That is one way to index content of a DB into Solr.

Comment: Yes. I solve it using the [guide](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/01/how-to-use-solr-data-import-handler-to.html). But now I have a problem with DataImportHandler and the error code is: sorry, no dataimport-handler defined!